# How do I position elements to the left beside an input field?

Tags: html, css

Starting my learning from scratch so, I'm making a mock google advanced home search page for practice. I'm struggling to position my elements according to the following image:

[image: Google's Advanced Search Page]

The image below is what I've got so far:

[image: Mock Google Advanced Search Page]

What CSS modifications do I need to make to achieve the correct positioning?

My code can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lggo9r?file=AdvancedSearch.html) however, for some reason the preview on stackBlitz isn't rendering it the same way as a standard web browser.

What CSS modifications do I need to make to achieve the correct layout?

Thank you

Comment: post your code here in a snippet

Answer (score 0):

If you only use html and css, here's a (very) simple example of a form implementation

```css
p{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

label {
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Find pages with ...</p>
<form>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
</form>
```